# Refresh images after uploading to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, firebase-storage

I am working on an Ionic 3 app with Angular 5 and Firebase. Using this example https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail The image is resized and a thumbnail is saved after an image is uploaded. However, I can't seem to get the image to refresh in the app after the thumbnail url is saved to the database.

This is the code which generates a list of guests for an event. The thumbnail changes after the app is restarted.

```
guestsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
guests: Observable<any[]>;

this.guestsRef = this.db.list(`attending/${id}`);
this.guests = this.guestsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes =>
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

HTML

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let guest of guests | async" class="guest-list">
            <ion-thumbnail item-start>
              <img [src]="guest.photoURL">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <p>{{(guest)?.first_name}} {{(guest)?.last_name}}</p>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

I save the `thumbFileUrl` to the database. Small snippet from the function sample found in the above url

```
}).then((results) => {
    console.log('Got Signed URLs.');
    const thumbResult = results[0];
    const originalResult = results[1];
    const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
    const fileUrl = originalResult[0];
    // Add the URLs to the Database
    return admin.database().ref('images').push({path: fileUrl, thumbnail: thumbFileUrl});
  }).then(() => console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.'));
```